# How to pass values ​from display to mutatuion - Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

How to pass values ​from display to mutatuion - Vue?

he return is an error indicating that the function does not exist.

Where can I be wrong?

Thank you guys

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import disponivel from './module-disponivel'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default function () {
  const Store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
      disponivel
    }
    )],
  })
  return Store
}
```

---

```
import store from '../store'

methods: {
     ...
},
display: function () {
      store.disponivel.commit('ValidationSet', true)
}
```

> Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError:
>   _store__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.default.disponivel is undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable [namespaced](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing) in your module, it should be

```
store.commit('disponivel/ValidationSet', true)
```

otherwise, it should be

```
store.commit('ValidationSet', true)
```

You might want to export your store as default:

```
export default const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
     disponivel
   }
})
```

Comment: [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: _store__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.default.commit is not a function"

Comment: [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: _store__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.default.commit is not a function"

Comment: Ittus, worked using store (). Commit function. However, it does not write to the module state.